# How to get numbers to come after decimal point in alphabetical sorting order in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, alphabetical

I have this `.sh` script that goes through every folder in a parent folder and runs `program` in each. The code I used was the following:

```
for d in ./*/
do cp program "$d"
(cd "$d" ; ./program)
done
```

`program`, among other things, gets the name of each folder and writes it to a file `data.dat`, so that all folder names are listed there. These folders' names are numbers (decimal) that identify their contents. `program` writes the folder name to `data.dat` when it enters each folder, so that they will appear in the order that Bash goes through the folders.

I want them to be sorted, in `data.dat`, in alphabetical order, putting lower numbers before higher, regardless of being a 1-digit or 2-digit number. For example, I want `2.32` to come before `10.43` and not the other way around.

The problem, it seems, is that for Bash the `.` comes after numbers in the order.
How can I change it to come before numbers?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
`program` is in Fortran 77 and goes like this:

`      program getData

```
  implicit none

  character counter*20, ac*4, bash*270, Xname*4, fname*15  
  double precision Qwallloss, Qrad, Nrad, Qth, QreacSUM
  double precision Xch4in, Ych4in, length, porosity, Uin, RHOin
  double precision MFLR, Area, Xvalue
  integer I

  bash="printf '%s\n'"//' "${PWD##*/}" > RunNumber.txt' 
  call system(bash)                   !this gets the folder name and writes 
                                      !to RunNumber.txt

  open(21, form="FORMATTED", STATUS="OLD", FILE="RunNumber.txt")
  rewind(21)
  read(21,*) counter            !brings the folder name into the program
  close(21)

  `
```

(...)
`

```
  call system(' cp -rf ../PowerData.dat . ')

  open(27, form="FORMATTED", STATUS="OLD", ACCESS="APPEND", !the new row is appended to the existing file
 1       FILE="PowerData.dat")

  write(27,600) Counter, Xvalue, Nrad, Qrad, Qth,  !writes a row of variables, 
 1     Area, MFLR, Uin, RHOin, Xch4in, Ych4in   !starting with the folder name, 
                                                !to the Data file
  close(27)

  call system('cp -rf PowerData.dat ../')


  end program`
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Given what you're asking the script you're posting has no impact on the desired result, but all hinges on `./program`.  Not knowing what or how `./program` does its thing  it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: I added the program code. The reason I think the problem is with bash sorting order is because it only does one folder at a time. He goes in, gets the folder name, gets the `PowerData.dat` (= `data.dat`) from the parent folder, writes the folder name in the data file and copies it back to the parent folder. Then goes into the next folder and repeats. So it will always be written in the order that entered the folders.

Comment: I'm starting to understand ... and I must say, this is a pretty perverse way of going about updating the file :D  But I now see why you think this is a bash issue. What you (if you can't come up with a better way of doing this, or just sorting the file once you're done) have to do it to generate a list of the directory structure, sort that by your criteria, and then iterate over that list.  There's no way to tell bash to glob in numerical order.

Comment: I'm a caveman with a club and a stone! :D Thanks, I will try and figure something out.

Comment: Jaja :D - you're funny.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that your `program` will in the future do perhaps a bit more and therefore I made the second loop.

```
for d in ./*/ ; do
    echo "$d"a >> /tmp/tmpfile
done
for d in $(sort -n  /tmp/tmpfile) ; do
    cp program "$d"
    (cd "$d" ; ./program)
done
```

There are more ways to do this; for example:

```
for d in $(ls | sort -n) ; do
```

(some will castigate me for parsing the output of `ls`) etcetera.

So if you do:

```
mkdir test
cd test
touch 100
touch 2.00
touch 50.1
```

`ls` will give you

```
100  2.00  50.1
```

`ls | sort -n` will give you

```
2.00
50.1
100
```

and, as a bonus, `ls -v` will give you

```
2.00  50.1  100
```

Comment: Have a look at my comment on the question;  the generation of the list (which is sorted wrong) happens within `./program`, your solution doesn't address the question. And it is in fact impossible to address since we don't know what `./program` looks like.

Comment: The OP stated that: "program, among other things, gets the name of each folder and writes it to a file data.dat, so that all folder names are listed there" . If you look at my first solution, you will see that the folders are now executed in the desired order and therefore the output-file will also be in the correct order. So, dear Tink, the solution is valid and gives the result that  the OP required.

Comment: Ooops ... must have had a distinct lack of coffee ... my profusest apologies.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion @LjmDullaart, but if I sort with `ls  | sort -n` (which my bash is doing automatically) the result is exactly the one I don't want. I get 100.0 as coming before 2.00.

Comment: That is really strange; the -n option for `sort` should sort numerically, which is not what `ls` does. It does so on Linux, AIX and Solaris. What system are you on that makes sort behave differently?

Comment: @tink: Since I made some comparable errors, I NEVER post anything before cofee anymore :-)

Comment: It's not my machine, but i believe it is standard Linux (i'm not too versed in the details, or at all). It does sort numerically, but it completely ignores `.` , i realize now. It would only sort appropriately if instead of `2.00` I had `002.00`, and that's not helpful for me to have. Anyways, I just went and coded some prehistoric stuff and it is working, so I guess I'm satisfied ':)

Comment: Added the tests that proof the correctness of the solution.

Comment: I tried your test case and it indeed works. But with my folder names it does not (I failed to mention bc I, wrongly it seems, assumed that it wouldnt make a difference, that the folders' names have numbers, letters and underscores (ex : `ASPC_85.079_117_`). Your last suggestion though, does work in sorting everything in the parent folder. Thanks very much for the patience!